# Push из VS2013 временных файлов Unity3D

Tags: visual-studio, git, unity3d

При отправке файла из VS2013 на GitHub выходит сообщение:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not open
>   'D:/CODE/Unity/Test/Temp/UnityLockfile': Процесс не может получить
>   доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.

Приходится закрывать Unity3D.

Как можно настроить, чтобы избежать неудобства?

Comment: Я вообще бы порекомендовал не заливать `temp`.... на то она и `temp`, что она постоянно меняется, там что-то временно хранится, потом удаляется и прочее. Как результат - хранить её не имеет смысла...Когда вы закрываете юнити, эта папка очищается и удаляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

каталоги с временными файлами лучше не хранить в системе контроля версий.

чтобы убрать каталог (или файл) из-под контроля версий (но не удалять сам каталог и файлы/каталоги внутри него), можно воспользоваться [командой `rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) с опцией `--cached`:

```
$ git rm --cached путь/к/каталогу/или/файлу
```

после чего зафиксировать изменения в репозитории, сделав коммит.

---

а чтобы этот каталог/файл впоследствии не отображался как «untracked file», можно добавить его в файл `.git/info/exclude` (это окажет влияние только на ваш локальный репозиторий) или `.gitignore` (а этот файл можно уже добавить в репозиторий, и тогда игнорируемый файл/каталог не будет отображаться и в других клонах вашего репозитория). см. [про игнорирование файлов](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9#%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Answer (score 0):

для проектов на Unity3d лучше использовать вот такой .gitignore

```
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/Assets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated VS/MD solution and project files
ExportedObj/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd


# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta

# Unity3D Generated File On Crash Reports
sysinfo.txt

#штука генерируемая проводником Windows
Thumbs.db
Thumbs.db.meta
```