# Как убрать некоторые файлы из следующего коммита?

Tags: git

У меня есть коммит, в который я случайно добавил файл, который не должен был. В текущем коммите не страшно, пусть будет. Но как сделать так, чтобы он убрался из следующего ?

Comment: `git rm <имя файла>` и коммитить. Но можно поправить и старый коммит

Comment: а `git rm` не удалит файл физически с жесткого диска ?

Comment: удалит конечно.

Comment: Но мне надо, чтобы файл остался на диске, но ушел из коммита.

Comment: Если файл не будет изменятся, то он и не будет попадать в коммит. Скорее всего Вы случайно закоммитили файл и не хотите, что бы git о нем знал, да?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518566/178576

Comment: @KoVadim да, верно

Comment: Тогда либо делайте как предложил @alexanderbarakin, но в этом случае одна версия файла останется в репозитории и при надобности ее можно "вытащить".  Если нужно вычистить с репозитория, тогда так - https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Comment: @KoVadim, здесь уже тоже описано не раз: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/426454/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в ответе, на который вы дали ссылку, решение через filter-branch, а в справке гитхаба - через bfg. Думаю, оба решения избыточны, если речь идёт о последнем коммите.

Comment: @NickVolynkin 1. в справке гитхаба изложено два способа. 2. второй мой комментарий был лишь дополнением к комментарию KoVadim-а.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git rm --cached foobar.txt` — удалит файл из Git, но оставит на диске.